# How to vectorize searching function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, vectorization

Here is a Matlab coding problem (A little different version with intersect not setdiff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506283/how-to-vectorize-searching-function-and-intersection-in-matlab):

a rating matrix A with 3 cols, the 1st col is user'ID which maybe duplicated, 2nd col is the item'ID which maybe duplicated, 3rd col is rating from user to item, ranging from 1 to 5.

Now, I have a subset of user IDs ***smallUserIDList*** and a subset of item IDs ***smallItemIDList***, then I want to find the rows in A that rated by users in ***smallUserIDList***, and collect the items that user rated, and do some calculations, such as setdiff with ***smallItemIDList*** and count the result, as the following code does:

```
userStat = zeros(length(smallUserIDList), 1);
for i = 1:length(smallUserIDList)
    A2= A(A(:,1) == smallUserIDList(i), :);
    itemIDList_each = unique(A2(:,2));

    setDiff = setdiff(itemIDList_each , smallItemIDList);
    userStat(i) = length(setDiff);
end
userStat
```

Finally, I find the profile viewer showing that the loop above is inefficient, the question is how to improve this piece of code with vectorization but the help of for loop?

**For example:**

*Input*:

```
A = [
1 11 1
2 22 2
2 66 4
4 44 5
6 66 5
7 11 5
7 77 5
8 11 2
8 22 3
8 44 3
8 66 4
8 77 5    
]

smallUserIDList = [1 2 7 8]
smallItemIDList = [11 22 33 55 77]
```

*Output*:

```
userStat =

 0
 1
 0
 2
```

Comment: It would be good if you added sample data and expected output so that people have something to compare their answers against.

Comment: I wonder if it would help if you put the calculation inside the loop in a function - that way the the optimization routine will recognize you only care about userStat and won't copy the other variables into the workspace.

Comment: Is it possible that there will be two entries with same userID and same itemID buth with different rating? If not, simply build a sparse matrix.

Comment: @kkuilla Hi! Good idea, I have added an example data and output to make the question more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vanilla MATLAB:

As far as I can tell your code is equivalent to:

```
%// Create matrix such that: user_item_rating(user,item)==rating
user_item_rating = sparse(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3));

%// Keep all BUT the items in smallItemIDList
user_item_rating(:,smallItemIDList) = [];

%// Keep only those users in `smallUserIDList` and use order of this list
user_item_rating = user_item_rating(smallUserIDList,:);

%// Count the number of ratings
userStat = sum(user_item_rating~=0, 2);
```

This will work if there is at most one rating per `(user,item)`-combination. Also it should be quite efficient.

### Clean approach without reinventing the wheel:

Check out [`grpstats`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/grpstats.html) from the Statistics Toolbox!
An implementation could look similar to this:

```
%// Create ratings table
ratings = array2table(A, 'VariableNames', {'user','item','rating'});

%// Remove items we don't care about (smallItemIDList)
ratings = ratings(~ismember(ratings.item, smallItemIDList),:);

%// Keep only users we care about (smallUserIDList) 
ratings = ratings(ismember(ratings.user, smallUserIDList),:);

%// Compute the statistics grouped by 'user'. 
userStat = grpstats(ratings, 'user');
```

Comment: Seems to work and quite fast indeed! Note to OP, use `full` to wrap up `userStat` to have a numeric array as output for the sparse approach.

Comment: @knedlsepp Hi! Sorry for delaying the response!! At first I try your first code, but didn't make it just for my carelessness of a wrong variable name!! Now, I find the bug and I can thank you for your answer for it really boost my running speed further for another 20 seconds reduction!! Truly shocking!! Would you like to give a look at my another two questions, 1st is added in the question link, 2nd is how to modify yours if "setIntersect = intersect(itemIDList_each , smallItemIDList); userStat(i) = length(setIntersect);" changes to "userStat(i) = length(itemIDList_each );". Thank you again!!

Answer (score 2):

This could be one `vectorized` approach -

```
%// Take care of equality between first column of A and smallUserIDList to 
%// find the matching row and column indices.
%// NOTE: This corresponds to "A(:,1) == smallUserIDList(i)" from OP.
[R,C] = find(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),smallUserIDList.')); %//'

%// Take care of non-equality between second column of A and smallItemIDList. 
%// NOTE: This corresponds to SETDIFF in the original loopy code from OP.
mask1 = ~ismember(A(R,2),smallItemIDList);

AR2 = A(R,2); %// Elements from 2nd col of A that has matches from first step

%// Get only those elements from C and AR2 that has ONES in mask1
C1 = C(mask1);
AR2 = AR2(mask1);

%// Initialized output array
userStat = zeros(numel(smallUserIDList),1);

if ~isempty(C1)%//There is at least one element in C, so do further processing
    
    %// Find the count of duplicate elements for each ID in C1 indexed into AR2.
    %// NOTE: This corresponds to "unique(A2(:,2))" from OP.
    dup_counts = accumarray(C1,AR2,[],@(x) numel(x)-numel(unique(x)));
    
    %// Get the count of matches for each ID in C in the mask1.
    %// NOTE: This corresponds to:
    %//       "length(setdiff(itemIDList_each , smallItemIDList))" from OP.
    accums = accumarray(C,mask1);
    
    %// Store the counts in output array and also subtract the dup counts
    userStat(1:numel(accums)) = accums;
    userStat(1:numel(dup_counts)) = userStat(1:numel(dup_counts)) - dup_counts;
end
```

---

### Benchmarking

The code listed next compares runtimes for proposed approach against the original loopy code -

```
%// Size parameters and random inputs with them
A_nrows    = 5000;
IDlist_len = 5000;
max_userID = 1000;
max_itemID = 1000;
A = [randi(max_userID,A_nrows,1) randi(max_itemID,A_nrows,1) randi(5,A_nrows,2)];
smallUserIDList = randi(max_userID,IDlist_len,1);
smallItemIDList = randi(max_itemID,IDlist_len,1);

disp('---------------------------- With Original Approach')
tic
%//   Original posted code
toc

disp('---------------------------- With Proposed Approach'))
tic
%//   Proposed approach code
toc
```

The runtimes thus obtained with three sets of datasizes were -

**Case #1:**

```
A_nrows    = 500;
IDlist_len = 500;
max_userID = 100;
max_itemID = 100;
---------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 0.136630 seconds.
---------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.004163 seconds.
```

**Case #2:**

```
A_nrows    = 5000;
IDlist_len = 5000;
max_userID = 100;
max_itemID = 100;
---------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 1.579468 seconds.
---------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.050498 seconds.
```

**Case #3:**

```
A_nrows    = 5000;
IDlist_len = 5000;
max_userID = 1000;
max_itemID = 1000;
---------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 1.252294 seconds.
---------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 0.044198 seconds.
```

**Conclusion:** The speedups with the proposed approach over the original loopy code thus seem to be huge!!

Comment: Hi! I have to say your code is so fast!! I use it and the time of data processing reduced at least 20 seconds!! Unbelievable!! In fact, the setdiff is just one branch of my code, I have another function which is to intersect instead of setdiff, would you help if the setdiff is replaced by intersect? Thanks so much!!

Comment: @archenoo That's really an awesome speedup!! Well, not sure how different would that be from the code in this posted problem. How about post that as a new question?

Comment: I post another question related this one and want an answer, thank you!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506283/how-to-vectorize-searching-function-and-intersection-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to remove a fixed set of ratings for a subset of users and count the number of remaining ratings:

Does the following work:

```
Asub = A(ismember(A(:,1), smallUserIDList),1:2);
Bremove = allcomb(smallUserIDList, smallItemIDList);
Akeep = setdiff(Asub, Bremove, 'rows');
T = varfun(@sum, array2table(Akeep), 'InputVariables', 'Akeep2', 'GroupingVariables', 'Akeep1');
% userStat = T.GroupCount;
```

you need the allcomb function from the file exchange from matlab central, it gives a cartesian product of two vectors, and  is easy to implement anyway.

Comment: I like the use of tables, but generating all `(smallUserIDList, smallItemIDList)` is a bit overkill.

Comment: BTW: Even after correcting the extra parentheses and the missing comma, the code doesn't work because in the `setdiff`-line the matrices don't have equal number of columns.

Comment: @alexandre iolov ,Hi! Thanks for you answer!! I tried your code and modified "Asub = A(ismember(A(:,1), smallUserIDList), :);" to "Asub = A(ismember(A(:,1), smallUserIDList), 1:2);", and "Var2" to "Akeep2", "Var1" to "Akeep1", then it works!! The result is userStat =

     1
     2 if using my example data, which is a bit different from the output I expect. However, I can learn many new methods from your code, thank you so much!!

Comment: @knedlsepp - thanks for the corrections. Both matrices should have had two columns, but i certainly did not try running the code - as I did not have an example of A, smallUserIDList, smallItemIDList and didn't bother inventing plausible ones. How would you avoid the cartesian product?

Comment: @alexandreiolov: Look at my answer involving tables. The `ismember` step could be applied in your answer too. I think the final `ratings` variable should match your `array2table(Akeep)`.