# How to vectorize searching function and Intersection in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, matrix, vectorization

Here is a Matlab coding problem (A little different version with setdiff not intersect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494489/how-to-vectorize-searching-function-in-matlab)):

a rating matrix A with 3 cols, the 1st col is user'ID which maybe duplicated, 2nd col is the item'ID which maybe duplicated, 3rd col is rating from user to item, ranging from 1 to 5.

Now, I have a subset of user IDs ***smallUserIDList*** and a subset of item IDs ***smallItemIDList***, then I want to find the rows in A that rated by users in ***smallUserIDList***, and collect the items that user rated, and do some calculations, such as intersect with ***smallItemIDList*** and count the result, as the following code does:

```
userStat = zeros(length(smallUserIDList), 1);
for i = 1:length(smallUserIDList)
    A2= A(A(:,1) == smallUserIDList(i), :);
    itemIDList_each = unique(A2(:,2));

    setIntersect = intersect(itemIDList_each , smallItemIDList);
    userStat(i) = length(setIntersect);
end
userStat
```

Finally, I find the profile viewer showing that the loop above is inefficient, the question is how to improve this piece of code with vectorization but the help of for loop?

**For example:**

*Input*:

```
A = [
1 11 1
2 22 2
2 66 4
4 44 5
6 66 5
7 11 5
7 77 5
8 11 2
8 22 3
8 44 3
8 66 4
8 77 5    
]

smallUserIDList = [1 2 7 8]
smallItemIDList = [11 22 33 55 77]
```

*Output*:

```
userStat =

 1
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: My first advice to you is to learn/use Python and Pandas, *joins* will do what I think you are describing very fast and easily. The biggest problem here is that your data structure isn't good. However, the matlab function *find* does finding pretty well and fast. You might want to use *intersect* as well. Does that help you?

Comment: Actually there are [joins](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html) in matlab as well.

Comment: @HjörturJónasson ,Hi! Thanks for your advice!! it's a new data structure to me and thanks for mensioning that!! I must say the sparse matrix in matlab is the main data structure that I used to learn, and now I don't know whether it is a better choice to learn table for the main concern is the scale of table, because even the bsxfun will give me an error of memory leak, would you like to give me some introduction to the performance comparison? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! You need a tiny edit in the accepted solution to the previous question. Here's the solution -

```
[R,C] = find(bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),smallUserIDList(:).')); %//'
mask = ismember(A(R,2),smallItemIDList(:).'); %//'# The edit was needed here

ARm = A(R,2);
Cm = C(mask);
ARm = ARm(mask);

userStat = zeros(numel(smallUserIDList),1);
if ~isempty(Cm)
    dup_counts = accumarray(Cm,ARm,[],@(x) numel(x)-numel(unique(x)));
    accums = accumarray(C,mask);
    userStat(1:numel(accums)) = accums;
    userStat(1:numel(dup_counts)) = userStat(1:numel(dup_counts)) - dup_counts;
end
```

---

As a bonus stuff, you can edit the pre-allocation step -

```
userStat = zeros(numel(smallUserIDList),1);
```

with this much faster pre-allocation scheme -

```
userStat(1,numel(smallUserIDList)) = 0;
```

Read more about it in this [`MATLAB Undocumented post on Pre-allocation`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance).

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I am  really a newbie in matlab.I have to ask the last question, would you have time to look it? if we change the code "setIntersect = intersect(itemIDList_each , smallItemIDList); userStat(i) = length(setIntersect);" to "userStat(i) = length(itemIDList_each );", how to modify in this code? Thanks again!!

Comment: @archenoo After the first step when you have `R` and `C`, use this `userStat = accumarray(C,A(R,2),[],@(x) numel(unique(x)))`. So, in that case, everything is done in two steps.

Comment: Thanks never too much for your careful and kind help!